# Generate PDF from large html

Tags: c#, html, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I am generating a PDF from an HTML string.
When this string is really long, I would like to create a new page, split the text (without breaking the html) and so on.

Here is my code :

```
// instantiate Pdf object
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();

// specify the Character encoding for for HTML file
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharSet = "UTF-8";
pdf.HtmlInfo.Margin.Left = 10;
pdf.HtmlInfo.Margin.Right = 10;
pdf.HtmlInfo.PageHeight = 1050;
pdf.HtmlInfo.PageWidth = 730;
pdf.HtmlInfo.ShowUnknownHtmlTagsAsText = true;
pdf.HtmlInfo.TryEnlargePredefinedTableColumnWidthsToAvoidWordBreaking = true;
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingLevelOfForce = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingForceLevel.UseWhenImpossibleDetectFromContent;
// bind the source HTML

pdf.BindHTML("MyVeryVeryLongHTML");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pdf.Save(stream);

byte[] pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
```

This code works for the HTML, but the overflow is not handled. The text continue after the page. Is it possible to set a max "height" of the page to not cross, and if it does, it recreates a new page ?

Hope it makes sense !

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Page height by selecting type of PDF page you require like A1, A2, etc . Afterwords , your problem of page height will automatically be taken care by the Aspose. For more refer the link..

[Aspose PDF Page Height](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Set+Page+Size+and+Margins)

Update

update `pdf.HtmlInfo` to `pdf.PageSetup (or pdf.PageInfo)` and add bottom margin also.

Comment: I've tried it already, but it still does the same thing. in my question, I put the code : pdf.HtmlInfo.PageHeight = 1050;
I'd also tried with pdf.HtmlInfo.PageHeight = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.PageSize.A4Height; - Same result

Comment: After `Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();` set page height and width that you are expecting ..

Comment: Ok, I got my error. It was because I did pdf.HtmlInfo instead of pdf.PageSetup (or pdf.PageInfo). I also had to add a bottom margin. Thanks for your reply, I will mark your answer as fixed. maybe just add my comment in your answer for next user that could help :)